# C++ Templates challenge

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, gcc

I've been facing a big challenge (for me, at least) regarding templates instancing and inheritance. Let's see this code:

```
class Convertible
{
    public:

    template<class T>
    T* AsPtrTo()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this);
    }
};

template<class T>
class TemplateBase : public Convertible
{
};

template<class T>
class TemplateDerived : public TemplateBase<T>
{
    public:

    void Method1(TemplateBase<T> t)
    {
        t.AsPtrTo<int>(); // <<<<<< ERROR
    }
};


int main()
{
    TemplateDerived<int> d;
    TemplateBase<int> b;
    d.Method1(b);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, there is a class, called Convertible, with only one template method that performs a type casting. There is also a template class that inherits from Convertible, and then another template class that inherits from the previous one. This last template class implements a method that uses the template method AsPtrTo which should be inherited from Convertible and instanced during compilation for the type T, used in the main function.

For some reason I can't understand, this fails. GCC 4.4.1 gives me this message:

> error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

I've marked the line of the error.

I thought maybe one of the C++ experts here could lend me a hand.

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: "`return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this)`" you aren't really doing that, are you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the keyword `template` as:

```
 t.template AsPtrTo<int>();
```

This has been discussed so many times that you will find innumerable number of posts on SO.

But here you will find one of the best explanation:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I searched for a post related to this but I couldn't find anything :(, surely I used the wrong keywords. The problem is now clear for me, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
void Method1(TemplateBase<T> t)
{
    t.template AsPtrTo<int>();
}
```

The reason is that the compiler doesn't know what member functions `t` has at parse time, so it doesn't know if `AsPtrTo` is a template function or not. Because of this, it can't parse it properly without the hint.

As an example for why this is needed, consider the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    template<int N> int foo(int x) { return x + N; }
};

struct Bar
{
    int foo;
}; 

template <typename T>
int baz(T t)
{
    return t.foo<0>(1);
}
```

At a glance, it looks like `baz<Foo>` would work, but `baz<Bar>` wouldn't, but it's the other way round!

Consider what happens if I call `baz<Bar>`

`return t.foo<0>(1);`

`foo` is a member variable, so when it sees the `<` it thinks it's a less-than operator, so it parses the expression like this:

`return (t.foo < 0) > (1);`

Which is a valid expression (after some implicit conversions to/from `bool`)!

The thing is, it parses the expression like that for both `Foo` and `Bar`, which is why the `template` keyword is needed. Compilers have to assume that it is not a template member function (unless you put that keyword there).